# Duplication of images following JavaScript success function running correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

Each time the "success" function of this code block executes, some unwanted events happen:

1. If I dont refresh the browser and enter the same name again, a duplicated image appears. This happens each time the code is run.
2. If I don't refresh the browser and type a name that doesn't exist, wheres before the search returned a name that did, then both images are displayed on the page.

How do I stop the duplication? I've looked at alternatives to .append in jQuery, but none are having the desired result.

I think I also need the query to reset each time its run, other wise it appears this also causes complication.

> var friendName;

```
function findFriend() {
    friendName = $('#friendsearch').val();
    console.log(friendName);
    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    query.equalTo("username", friendName); // find users that match
    query.find({
        success: function (friendMatches) {
            // This section is always run, no matter the outcome. Depending on the input depends on which result is shown
            if (friendMatches.length === 0)
            // console.log('NO MATCH FOUND!!!');
                $(".no_user").show();

            else // Query executed with success
                imageURLs = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < friendMatches.length; i++) {
                var object = friendMatches[i];
                imageURLs.push(object.get('pic'));
            }
            // If the imageURLs array has items in it, set the src of an IMG element to the first URL in the array
            for (var j = 0; j < imageURLs.length; j++) {
                $('#imgs').append("<img src='" + imageURLs[j] + "'/>");
            }


            console.log('MATCH FOUND!!!');
        },

        // Only if the code breaks and cannot either find or not find a user should this error be returned
        error: function (error) {
            alert('Opps we have a problem' + error.message);
        }
    });
}

// This captures the users input and is triggered when the user presses the find

$('#find_button').click(function (e) {
    findFriend();
});
```

Comment: Use `.html()` to change all the content inside the element. That will stop the duplication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the old image(s) before adding the new one(s):

```
$('#imgs').empty();
```

When to clear is another issue (I think this is your 'unwanted event #2'):

```
success: function (friendMatches) {
    // clear images first, so that previous search results
    // don't show when the current search returns 0 results
    $('#imgs').empty();
    ...
}
```